# Codeigniter - My Model Jamie Rumbelow + HMVC callback validation in model

Tags: codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-hmvc

i wonder how to use callback validation using MY model - made by Jamie Rumbelow with Modular extension - wiredesignz

i have create MY_Form_validation and modified the run function like this:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

/**
 * Stores the CodeIgniter core object.
 *
 * @access public
 *
 * @var object
 */
public $CI;



/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @return void
 */
function __construct($config = array())
{
    // Merged super-global $_FILES to $_POST to allow for better file validation inside of Form_validation library
    $_POST = (isset($_FILES) && is_array($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0) ? array_merge($_POST,$_FILES) : $_POST;

    parent::__construct($config);

}
/**
 * Performs the actual form validation
 *
 * @access public
 *
 * @param string $module Name of the module
 * @param string $group  Name of the group array containing the rules
 *
 * @return bool Success or Failure
 */
public function run($module='', $group='')
{
    (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI =& $module;
    return parent::run($group);

}
```

it work perfectly if i run form validation with callback in controller, but i wonder how to run in inside a model, it always skip the callback

thank you for your time, and your answer :)

Comment: Did you see there is something to add in case you use HMVC and form validation callback : http://www.mahbubblog.com/php/form-validation-callbacks-in-hmvc-in-codeigniter/ ?

Comment: thank you for your comment, yes i've followed his tutorial, but it only work in public callback function